# What exceptions can Jtoken.ToObject<T>() throw?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Is there a list of exceptions that `JToken.ToObject<T>()` can throw? Their [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm) doesn't mention anything.

```
var deserialized = myJtoken.ToObject<myType>(); // what can this throw?
```

Comment: Newtonsoft doesn't document the exceptions they might throw.  The [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64934419/3744182) gives the exceptions thrown *directly* by `ToObject<T>()` but the serializer can throw any subtype of [`JsonException`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonException.htm).  And [custom converters](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) can throw any exception they please.  And of course other exceptions might get thrown in the event of a Newtonsoft bug.

Comment: I appreciate the answers, although I'm not sure what details or clarity was required. Any pointers?

Comment: I'm not sure why it was closed as "Needs Details or Clarity", the question seems clear enough.  The only problem I see is that there's no answer other than "could be anything, it's not documented."

Comment: That makes sense to me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have examined, according to [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/a222c8b69cc8ae55d938339362c2550c939a1e4d/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs), there are two obvious exceptions:

```
ArgumentException
ArgumentNotNull
```

But this may not be a complete list of exceptions, there might be other exceptions within internal methods.